# #states hide by radio won't work

Tags: 8, javascript

The problem is all in the title. So here is my code (i cut some part to make it more visible) :

Constructor :

```
public function __construct() {
  $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
  $this->sub_forms['user'] = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($user);
}
```

buildForm :

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $sub_forms_keys = array_keys($this->sub_forms);
  // INC ALL SUBFORM INTO THE MAIN FORM
  foreach ($this->sub_forms as $key => $sub_form) {
    // REMOVE THE PROCESS CALLBACK
    if (!empty($sub_form['#process'])) {
      unset($sub_form['#process']);
    }

    // ALTER THE SUBFORM
    if ($key == $sub_forms_keys[0]) {
      // user Alter
      foreach ($sub_form as $field_key => $sub_form_field) {
        // Pour tous les champs                
        if (substr($field_key, 0, 10) != 'field_user') {
          // Si ce n'est pas un champ personnalisé friterie
          unset($sub_form[$field_key]); // Cacher le champ
        }
        else if (array_key_exists('widget', $sub_form[$field_key])) 
          // Si c'est un champ friterie et qu'il dispose d'un widget
          $sub_form_field_widget = $sub_form[$field_key]['widget'][0];
          $sub_form_field_widget['#states'] = array(
            'visible' => array(
              ':input[#edit-proprietaire-0]' => array('checked' => true),
            )
          );
          dsm($sub_form_field_widget);
        }
      }
    }

    // ADD THE SUBFORM INTO THE MAIN FORM
    $form[$key] = [
      '#type' => 'container',
      'form' => $sub_form
    ];
  }
  return $form;
}
```

Here is a pastern link of a dsm() of a field to show you the structure and that the #states is include : http://pastebin.com/1a8AqVzm

Then here is the HTML code of the entity i want to focus (it's a radio button) :

```
<input class="clear-panel-field panel-field-inline container-inline form-radio" data-drupal-selector="edit-proprietaire-0" type="radio" id="edit-proprietaire-0" name="proprietaire" value="0">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'#states' => array(
  'visible' => array(
    ':input[name="your checkbox"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
  ),
)
```

add this to the element you want to hide.this will be visible only when the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
'#states' => array(
  'visible' => array(
    ':input[name="check box name"]' => array('value' => 'value'),
  ),
),
```

This will hide dependency field based on input checked, even if it true.